# Retrieving Data from JSON Endpoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm using the Drupal iOS SDK to retrieve data from an entity (Comments) using the following code in my ViewController:

**ViewController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *comments;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *userReviews;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSDictionary *entityData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"] forKey:@"uid"];

    [DIOSEntity
     entityGet:entityData
     name:@"entity_comment"
     eid:@"uid"
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, id response) {
         self.comments = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:(NSDictionary*)response];


         NSLog(@"This is all of the data from response %@", response);
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
           //  [self.tableView reloadData];
         });
     }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, NSError *err) { NSLog(@"failed to get data"); }
     ];
```

The JSON data is returned and displayed in my console like so:

```
2016-01-08 21:53:13.213 app[2382:935044] Comments are as follows (
    {
        changed = 1450564731;
        cid = 1;
        "comment_body" =         {
            und =             (
                                {
                    format = "filtered_html";
                    "safe_value" = "<p>Christina is amazing with pets; I would recommend her to all users.</p>\n";
                    value = "Christina is amazing with pets; I would recommend her to all users.";
                }
            );
        };
)
```

I'm trying to display what's returned from the "comment_body" in a UILabel (the XML at the endpoint looks like this):

```
<comment_body>
<und is_array="true">
<item>
<value>
Christina is amazing with pets; I would recommend her to all users.
</value>
<format>filtered_html</format>
<safe_value>
<p>Christina is amazing with pets; I would recommend her to all users.</p>
</safe_value>
</item>
</und>
</comment_body>
```

**My question:** What should the code look like in order to retrieve that line? I'm thinking it should look something like...

```
self.userReviews.text = [self.comments objectForKey:@"comment_body"];
```

But comments is an NSMutableArray (and thus, that line won't work). Any help is appreciated; thank you!

Comment: Console data is not Matching braces, Could you check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
 self.userReviews.text = [[[[[self.comments objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"comment_body"] objectForKey:@"und"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"value"];
```

Comment: FYI - this can be written more easily as `self.userReviews.text = self.comments[0][@"comment_body"][@"und"][0][@"value"];`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a NSDictionary instead, like this:

```
 { 
        NSDictionary *jsonDictionary= [NSDictionary alloc]init]
             jsonDictionary= response;

            self.userReviews.text=[[[[jsonDictionary valueForKey:@"comment_body"]valueForKey:@"und"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"value"]; 
}
```

Comment: App crashes with the following error using those lines: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Yes, that's because "und" there appears to be an array, sorry I missed that, will edit my answer.

Comment: Edited my answer but not sure if it works, can not check it myself.